# Overriding WPF control colors programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf

My problem is - I'am developing a WPF Application which uses a Blue/Brown color theme. I set up all of the colors on the controls respectively but I'am running into a problem. WPF doesn't let you change some of the system colors such as the Highlight Color. I would like to know how could I possibly change the colors with C# code but not XAML.

Comment: Of course you can change the highlight color. Just define a brush resource with the right key in XAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure there is a way in c#. in the XAML code its easy. enter this into the style for the item.

```
   <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
```

then configure the "IsMouseOver" event with the fill color you choose, in your triggers for that item.

```
   <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
   <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{EnterColorInfoHere}"/>
   </Trigger>
```

Hope this helps. by the way. Don't fear the XAML...